# data.table: cast column to timeStamp wont work

Tags: r, data.table

Im using data.table version 1.9.4. and I have the following R script:

```
library(data.table)
asTimeStamp = function(strangeDateString) {
  # dates of the form YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.xxxxxx
  # i.e. for example
  #   2015-02-26 23:56:13.023467
  formatString = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"
  return(strptime(strangeDateString, formatString))
}
dt = data.table(timeAsString = c("2000-01-01 12:00:00.000000", "2000-01-01 12:01:00.000000"))
dt[, x := asTimeStamp(timeAsString)]
```

which is supposed to generate a second column 'x' in the data table

```
                 timeAsString
1: 2000-01-01 12:00:00.000000
2: 2000-01-01 12:01:00.000000
```

that contains 'timeAsString' in some computable format like POSIXwhatever. The script throws the error

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(x, asTimeStamp(timeAsString))) :
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 2 items of column 'x' (9 unused)
```

and I obtain the following data table:

```
                 timeAsString   x
1: 2000-01-01 12:00:00.000000 0,0
2: 2000-01-01 12:01:00.000000 0,1
```

maybe I am using it wrongly but I thought that

```
dt[, newColumn := function(oldColumns)]
```

like, for example

```
dt[, newColumn := oldColumn + 1]
```

is supposed to execute 'function' on 'oldColumn' and put the result to 'newColumn'... ?

NB: the commands

```
print(asTimeStamp(dt$timeAsString));
print(dt[, asTimeStamp(timeAsString)]);
```

both work so the function appears to be correct...

THX, Regards,

FW

Comment: My guess is that's because `strptime` contains additonal `$names` attribute which `data.table` don't know how to handle, see `attributes(strptime("2000-01-01 12:00:00.000000", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))` (it contains 11 values within the `$names` attribute). Though, you don't really need this function, and you can just replace it with `return(as.POSIXct(strangeDateString, format = formatString))` within your function call and it will work as expected.

Comment: `strptime` returns `POSIXlt`, I believe you need to cast it to `POSIXct` to use in data.table.

Comment: Ah thanks, guys. It works :-) Could you phrase this as an answer? Ill accept then.

Comment: @jangorecki not sure what your comment added to mine though.

Comment: @DavidArenburg not much, but it is the root of the problem so I've highlight it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, its R getting in my way again. The strange warning comes from the fact that on the way POSIXlt --> data.table entry R tries to cast the POSIXlt element to something weird (maybe a list or so?) because a data.table only seems to accept 'basic' data types.

So, whenever you want to do multiple things with, as in my case, timeStamps, you have to leave them as a character and do the casting *every* time you want to do operations. Example: sort the table by timeStamp and then calculate the difference to 'now' in days
Ideal solution:
Create a new column that contains the timeStamp in a computable format and use this column every time you do operations.

--> does not work (see above)

'Slow' solution:
do the casting on the fly everytime you do operations with the timeStamps but always leave them as strings in the data.table:

1) sorting by timeStamp

```
dt = dt[rev(order(asTimeStamp(timeAsString), decreasing = TRUE)),]
```

2) calculate difference to 'now'

```
now = Sys.time()
dt = dt[, diffToNowInDays := difftime(asTimeStamp(timeAsString), now, units="days")]
```

--> I need to cast 2 times :-(

Comment: There is no need to resort to characters. `POSIXct` should work and is preferable over `POSIXlt` in most situations anyway.